# Custom archive template for a query on more taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i have a wp_query that search for products that appartains to more categories.

This is my code:

```
 $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'auto',
            'field' => 'ID',
            'terms' => $auto_id
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ricambio',
            'field' => 'ID',
            'terms' => $ricambi_id
        )
    ),
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'orderby' => 'title',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

In this case, how can i specify a custom archive template for this query ?

A sort of archive-product-term1-term2.php

Thanks